# Blob Data corrupt when use Ajax proxy

Tags: webservices, jquery, ajax, ajax-toolkit

Hi I want to get image from a public url and want to display this on page.
For doing this I am making an ajax proxy request because public url is on cross domain:

```
                sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
                        url : newURL,
                        mimeType: 'text/plain',
                        onSuccess:function(response){
                        console.log(newURL);
                               var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = function(){
                                  var dataURL = reader.result;
                                  var output = document.getElementById(imageID);
                                  output.src = dataURL;
                                };
                                 var blob = new Blob([response], {type: "image/png"});
                                 console.log(blob);
                                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);


                        }
                        });
```

But the image is corrupted and data url is also not write.

Please help me and guide me if I am doing anything wrong.